# NHibernate inheritance create child object from parent

Tags: c#, oop, nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate

I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but i just can't seem to get a grip.

I got 2 classes, `Customer` and `Member`.

**Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual string Firstname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Middlename { get; set; }
    public virtual string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

**Member.cs**

```
public class Member : Customer
{
    public virtual string MemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual string MemberRegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string MembershipStatus { get; set; }

    public Member()
    {
        MemberRegistrationDate = DateTime.Now;
        MembershipStatus = MembershipStatusEnum.Active;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this has to be an inheritance, in which Member **is a** Customer, though if I'm being desperate I can resort to composition.

Note that here I'm using NHibernate that forces me to use all that virtuals.

Given a single customer object, how should a new Member from an existing Customer ?

I can think of 2 options here :

**1 - Using Member.cs constructors to recreate it's parents properties**

Is this a good thing to do? I tried to do this :

```
public class Member : Customer
{
    public virtual string MemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual string MemberRegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string MembershipStatus { get; set; }

    public Member(Customer customer)
    {
       Firstname = customer.Firstname;
       Middlename = customer.Middlename;
       Lastname = customer.Lastname;

       MemberRegistrationDate = DateTime.Now;
       MembershipStatus = MembershipStatusEnum.Active;
    }
}
```

But Resharper warns me about accessing virtual member in a constructor, which I do agree to avoid, and tells me to make Member a sealed class which cannot have virtual members (no NHibernate compatibility).

It also raises another issue when someday I added a new property to Customer class, and I forgot to do the same to Member constructor.

**2 - Using some sort of reflection helper to map between two objects.**

Sure it's a viable option, but I'm currently learning about DDD and I'm wondering if it's okay to put such helper in the domain layer?

Need some suggestions, thanks !

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't exactly understand your problem. What do you mean with 'registering'? (It's not a term commonly used in OOP...)

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry for being unclear. The closest meaning will be creating a new Member (child) object from an existing Customer (parent) object, and copies all the existing parent properties to the child

Comment: Oh, does that mean: You have a Customer, and you want to create a new Member from it ('turn a Customer into a member'), while giving the additional properties some defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get you right, but there's no need to do anything `Customer` related in your `Member` class. You only need to tell NHibernate that Member derives from Customer, and you need to provide the correct mapping for both classes. That's it, the rest goes automatically (that's the whole point of inheritance in OOP, anyway).

Regarding your second issue ('Don't call virtuals in c'tor.'): That's theoretically true, but only relevant if there's a chance that the virtual method gets overwritten in a derived class. So you could safely ignore the R# warning here.

But I think it's cleanest here to get rid of the Member c'tor altogether and declare the class like so:

```
public class Member : Customer
{
    private memberRegistrationDate = DateTime.Now;
    private membershipStatus = MembershipStatusEnum.Active;

    public virtual string MemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual string MemberRegistrationDate 
    { 
      get { return this.memberRegistrationDate; }; 
      set { this.memberRegistrationDate = value; }; 
    }
    public virtual string MembershipStatus 
    { 
      get { return this.membershipStatus; }; 
      set { this.membershipStatus = value; }; 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
If you're looking for an easy way to turn a customer, into a member, you should maybe entirely keep the conversion code away from your classes and put it into an extension method instead (to keep things clean):

```
public static class CustomerExtensions
{
    public static Member ToMember(this Customer customer)
    {
        var member = new Member();
        member.Firstname = customer.Firstname;
        member.Middlename = customer.Middlename;
        member.Lastname = customer.Lastname;

        return member;
    }
}
```

You can call it then like this:

```
Member member = customer.ToMember();
```

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure I gets it.. Can you give me an example how to 'cast' a Customer to Member?

Comment: Edited the answer. Is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Well.. not really, it's a lot like my first option, which an issue when I wanted to add a new property to Customer. That's just one think that I can think of..

Comment: Basically, you're right. But if you want to implement the 'add new properties automatically' thing, this would be only possible with complicated and very slow reflection code. I doubt that this would be worth it.

Comment: I do want to avoid using Reflection as much as I can.. I'll be waiting for another opinion, but if there are none or there is a similar one, I'll accept your answer :)